# Problem trying to count number of words in a for loop

Tags: python

Trying to count the total number of words in a for loop but sum() method isn't working and failed trying to use list-append method:

```html
for line in open("jane_eyre.txt"):
  strip = line.rstrip()
  words = strip.split()
  for i in words:
    length = len(i)
    if length > 10 and "e" not in i:
      print(i)
      #Can't find a way to make it work here..
      sum(i)
```

The output of the words are:

```html
possibility
drawingroom
disposition
drawingroom
introductory
accumulation
introductory
surrounding
continually
inflictions
```

*Couldn't find a way to make get "10" as the sum.

Thanks.

Comment: `i` is a single word.  Just what do you think that `sum(i)` is supposed to do?  For instance, what would `sum("drawingroom")` give you?  If you're trying to count words, why are you manipulating individual words?

Comment: Why is there a check for words length, and another for the letter 'e'?

Comment: Python sum() function takes an iterable and returns the sum of items in it. You may want to look at some of these examples [geek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-function-python/) or [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp) or python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this...

```
c = 0 #number of words
for line in open("jane_eyre.txt"):
  strip = line.rstrip()
  words = strip.split()
  for i in words:
    length = len(i)
    if length > 10 and "e" not in i:
        print(i)
        #Can't find a way to make it work here..
        c +=1 #increasing number of words
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum()` is not what you're looking for here. To understand `sum()` usage better, have a read of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

You can store a `wordcount` prior to the loop and increase the value every time you match your `if` statement.

```
words = ['hello', 'these', 'are', 'words', 'they', 'get', 'longer', 'indtroductory']
wordcount = 0

for word in words:
    if len(word) > 10 and "e" not in word:
        print(word)
        wordcount += 1

#indtroductory
print(wordcount)
#1
```

If you need to access the words later, you could append them to a list and count the objects that exist within the list to obtain the count as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try here:

```
count = 0
for line in open("jane_eyre.txt"):
  strip = line.rstrip()

  words = strip.split()

  for i in words:
    length = len(i)
    if length > 10 and "e" not in i:
        print(i)
        #Can't find a way to make it work here..
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```